# Converting wmic memory stats in KB from bytes

Tags: batch-file

Using below code , i am getting workingSetSize in bytes.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

(For /F "delims=" %%A in ('"wmic process where Caption='Notepad.exe' get  ProcessId,WorkingSetSize /format:Texttable |findstr "[0-9P]" "') do (
set "line=%%A"
echo !line:~0,-1!
))>out.txt
```

can i get this memory in KB in above code ?

**EDIT1:**

i have modified code as:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(For /F "delims=" %%A in ('"wmic process where Caption='Notepad.exe' get      ProcessId,WorkingSetSize /format:Texttable |findstr "[0-9P]" "') do (
set "mem=%%B"
set /a mem=mem/1024
echo %%A !mem! 
))>out.txt
```

and getting output as:

```
ProcessId  WorkingSetSize  0 
5816       9142272         0 
5246       5673423         0
```

but i don't want those 0's, i need like below only:

```
ProcessId  WorkingSetSize  
5816       9142272        
5246       5673423
```

**EDIT2**

if i am using below code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(For /F "tokens=1,2" %%A in ('"wmic process where Caption='Notepad.exe' get   ProcessId,WorkingSetSize /format:Texttable |findstr "[0-9P]" "') do (
set "mem=%%B"
set /a mem=mem/1024
echo %%A !mem! 
))>new.txt
```

then output is coming like:

```
ProcessId 0 
5216      6112 
1152      6524
```

Comment: Don't use `"delims="` when advised to use `"tokens=1,2"`.

Comment: Ansgar..pls see **EDIT2**...:)

Comment: Of course you can't divide a header by 1024. You could do something like `echo !mem! | findstr /ri "[^0-9]" >nul || set /a "mem=mem/1024"`, which checks if `!mem!` contains characters other than digits and divides the variable by 1024 only if it doesn't.

Comment: @Ansgar...is there any solution if values exceed 2 GB limit ?

Comment: how this :http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_math.php can resolve 2 GB limit constraint of batch math ?

Comment: That is already explained in that article. I'm not going to read it to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the numbers will always be less than 2 GB then you can use this

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(For /F "tokens=1,2" %%A in ('"wmic process where Caption='HsvDataSource.exe' get  ProcessId,WorkingSetSize /format:Texttable |findstr "[0-9]" "') do (
set "mem=%%B"
set /a mem=mem/1024
echo PID:%%A %%B=!mem! KB
))>out.txt
```

Solution to your **EDIT2** above

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
>new.txt echo ProcessId  WorkingSetSize
(For /F "tokens=1,2" %%A in ('"wmic process where Caption='Notepad.exe' get   ProcessId,WorkingSetSize /format:Texttable |findstr "[0-9]" "') do (
set "mem=%%B"
set /a mem=mem/1024
echo %%A !mem! 
))>>new.txt
```

Comment: @Foxi..ohhh..why didn't i think that an Echo could do the work..!!.btw thanks.:)

Comment: @Foxi..is there any solution if values exceed 2 GB limit ?

Comment: I too have the same question Sunny, I think you can skip the list three digits using ~0,-3 substring extraction and go further. This is because the size of a KB is 1024 bytes and technically, the above skip operation equal to dividing the number with 1000, instead of the 1024.